# String field from SharePoint form library only returning first 255 characters with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

In JavaScript I am using Microsoft Graph API against a form library in SharePoint Online and while one of the "text (string)" fields holds over 255 characters, when reading the field only the first 255 characters are returned. The fields defined as "Rich Text (XHTML)" do not seem affected. Is there a way around this besides redefining the field in the form library (which is not an option for me)?

Comment: What is "a string field"? There are two major field types: Text and Note. Text can only store 255 characters - and never more. Note can store more than that. Are you sure your field is not a Text field?

Comment: When I open the form in InfoPath and look at the field it says "text (string)" instead of the other option which is "Rich Text (XHTML)". The field causing the issue is a "text (string)" field. Looking at the raw XML I can assure you the field holds more than 255 characters. But when seen in a view or when Microsoft Graph is used only 255 characters are retrieved/displayed. I will edit the question so it says "text (string)".

Comment: What if you check that field's type in List Settings in SharePoint itself?

Comment: The field properties of a form library cannot be viewed from the list view. You can see the field names but you cannot click on them. I assume this is by design since they were created from the form.